# Will copying an object and changing this copy variable not change the original one?

Tags: javascript, redux

Suppose I have this object:

```
const obj = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: {
        d: 'hi'
      }
    },
    g: 23
  },
  f: {
    e: [1,2]
  }
}
```

To change the variable "d" it without mutating it, will this:

```
const newObj = {...obj};
newObj.a.b.c.d = 'Bye';
return newObj;
```

work?

This is in regards to redux...

Comment: Why don't you try?!

Comment: No. A spread is only a shallow copy, so `obj.a` and `newObj.a` points to the same object.

Comment: @ASDFGerte please don't forget that SO is primarily meant as a resource for reference, so in my opinion, it does make sense to ask questions like these (and answer them)

Comment: @PatrickHund I see the value in asking this question, as there may be some detail, that cannot be easily found by a naive test. However, anyone actually trying, and having done any attempt, would have a differently structured question - if a test shows, that it doesn't work in some case, then the question "will it generally work" doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ASDFGerge mentioned, you should play around with this to really internalize it.

But the short answer is no, your copy `newObj` is only a copy 1 level deep. Changing `newObj.a` will not modify the original, but changing `newObj.a.b` (or anything further down) will.

```js
const original = {
  one: {
    two: {
      three: 3
    },
    otherTwo: 2
  },
  otherOne: 1
}

const copy1LevelDeep = {...original};
copy1LevelDeep.one.two.three = 30;
copy1LevelDeep.one.two = {three: 300, four: 4};
copy1LevelDeep.one.otherTwo = 20;
copy1LevelDeep.one = 100;
copy1LevelDeep.otherOne = 10;

console.log(original);
console.log(copy1LevelDeep);
```

Comment: Thanks! So I'll have to spread each level to completely copy it

Answer (score 3):

**No** – only the first level of properties of `obj` will be copied when you spread it with the spread operator `...`.

This is called shallow copy, as opposed to deep copy.

```js
const obj = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: {
        d: "hi"
      }
    },
    g: 23
  },
  f: {
    e: [1, 2]
  }
};

const newObj = { ...obj };
newObj.a.b.c.d = "Bye";

console.log(obj.a.b.c.d); // Bye
```